# Toggle div on Link[same link class on various] click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an scenario on which i need to toggle div on link click.
But here catch is that we have links with ***same class [to click]** and **same class[to open/toggle]**

Toggle is working fine but i need

- "Toggle my text" has opened next "textBox"
- Now if user has clicked on "Toggle my text2" then

  - "textbox" of "Toggle my text" shall be closed[not working currently]
  - "textbox" of Toggle my text2 shall be opened.[working currently]

and vice versa.

Here is JS fiddle link

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xe18wusw/)

Some of Code is as below:

```
$(function () {
  $(".textBox").hide();
  $('a.clickMe').click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll('div.textBox:first').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to hide the other divs.

```js
$(function () {
    $(".textBox").hide();
    $('a.clickMe').click(function () {
        var target = $(this).nextAll('div.textBox:first');
        $(".textBox").not(target).hide();
        target.toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
a{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
<br />
<div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<a class="clickMe">Toggle my text2</a>
<br />
<div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>
```

**EDIT:** Following your comment, here is how you would do using classes.

```js
$(function () {
    // you may want to set the hidden class directly in the html
    // instead of the line below to avoid the text boxes appearing
    // before the js executed the first time.
    $(".textBox").addClass("hidden");
    $('a.clickMe').click(function () {
        var target = $(this).nextAll('div.textBox:first');
        $(".textBox").not(target).addClass("hidden");
        target.toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<a class="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
<br />
<div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<a class="clickMe">Toggle my text2</a>
<br />
<div class="textBox"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/xe18wusw/6/

```
$(function () {
$(".textBox").hide();
$('a.clickMe').click(function () {
    var thisElem = this;
    var isVisibe = $(thisElem).nextAll('div.textBox:first').is(":visible");
    $(".textBox").each(function(i,elem){
        console.error(thisElem,elem)
        if(thisElem!==elem){
            $(elem).hide();
        }
    });
   // if()
    $(thisElem).nextAll('div.textBox')[isVisibe ? "hide" : "show"]();
    $(thisElem).nextAll('.clickMe:first').nextAll("div.textBox").hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: this is giving me errors in console.. returns same HTML element